# Lines and text doesn't appear on same page in Latex

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

I was trying to take a dig at LaTeX and wanted to write a resume in it, but before I start writing the resume I wanted to learn the quintessential of latex. While trying to create a line I encountered some issues.

When I draw a line beneath or above the text , while generating pdf (using pdflatex) the lines doesn't appear in the same page , rather lines appear in a new page and text in different.

Here is the code

```
%Trying out rules in Latex

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\title{Rules in \LaTeX{}}
\line(1,0){250}
\author{Shashwat Pant}
\maketitle


\end{document}
```

If I use `\hrulefill` or `\line` I only get line in the document but no text if I use Texmaker, however if I compile it using `pdflatex` I get the line in the front page and text in other.
So how do I actually draw a line horizontal line touching each end of the sheet yet stay beneath some text, like a separator.

Comment: `\line` is supposed to be only used in a `picture` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typesetting the title is a job for the `\maketitle` command, which relies on the internal command `\@maketitle`, so you have to modify this one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em
  \begin{center}
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}
    \vskip 1.5em
  %%% Addition
    \hrule
    \vskip 1.5em
  %%% End addition
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}
    \vskip 1em
    {\large \@date}
  \end{center}
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Rules in \LaTeX{}}
\author{Shashwat Pant}
\maketitle


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, but since i am a beginner I don't understand some of the stuff.

What if i want to enter a line beneath a normal text and not in the title ? What then ?

Also which document class should I use for creating resume since text in the article class appears to be centered .

Comment: @Shashwat This is a very special case; for rules in the text there's `\rule`.